# Codeigniter Jquery Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Trying to auto input value from database while selecting something or changing selection. Here is my code. Not working.

Html part:

```
<select id="product">
     <option value="">Select A Product</option>
     <option value="Abc">Abc</option>
     <option value="Def">Def</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="quantity">
```

JS part:

```
$('#product').on('change', function() {
        var quan = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'order/ajaxReq/'+quan,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {quan: quan},
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $('#quantity').val(data);
        })

    });
```

Controller part:

```
public function ajaxReq()
  {
      $data['value'] = $this->order->getVal();
      foreach ($value as $row) {
          echo $quantity = $row->quantity;
      }
  }
```

Model Part:

```
public function getVal()
    {
        $quantity = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->db->where('quantity',$quantity);
        $query = $this->db->get('order_products');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couples of things need to fix. Follow these steps.
In JS code use following snippet :

```
$('#product').on('change', function() {
    var quan = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url("order/ajaxReq")?;>',// <--- here
        type: 'post',
        data: {quan: quan},// we send data parameter using data properties
        /* or use 
        success : function( data ) {
           $('#quantity').val(data);
        }*/
    })
    /*.success(function(data) { //<---- .success now replaced by .done, use that instead, otherwise declare these as a ajax properties
        $('#quantity').val(data);
    })*/
    .done(function(data) { //<---- we use .done here  
         $('#quantity').val(data);
    })
});
```

In your controller :

```
public function ajaxReq() {
  $quan = $this->input->post( 'quan' );
  $value = $this->order->getVal($quan);
  echo $value['quantity']; //<-- here these value will available on ajax success
}
```

And finally inside your model :

```
public function getVal($quan){
    $this->db->select('*'); // or select by fields
    $this->db->from('order_products');
    $where = array('quantity' => $quan );
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: how can add more than one variable in ajax data?, i added like this `data: {city:city,area:area},` but no process. but works fine for single variable.

Comment: `data: {city:city,area:area}`, this should work. What errors you got?

Comment: yes, it works, because of ajax it is difficult to find errors from controller and model.